# 2 UIView, one single Controller

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an application composed of a main view and a secondary view which is used to define parameters used by the first view. Both views have their own .xib  . In order to simplify the management of the application, I Would like to have the same controller (same class ans same instance) for both views. 
How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subclass of UIView as your controller's view that can load and display either of your views as subviews.